# SQL Server Configuration Manager 'Invalid class' Error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Getting an error while trying to connect to the reporting server and when I click 'find' it returns a message `Invalid class`. The reporting service is also running.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there are two databases (reportserver are present in SSMS). Check the database data and status. If database is not available then try to uninstall *ssrs* and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on MS SQL 2016. To solve the problem, I reinstalled MS SQL Server and chose not to configure Report Server during installation. After that, everything worked for me.